# PostgreSQL concurrent index creation - invalid index

Tags: postgresql, concurrency

We have the requirement to contain index size without locking tables. I tried to use 'create index concurrently ..' but it was resulting in INVALID index being created on one of the systems.We tried to do 
- drop index
- drop index concurrently
- reindex table
However intermittently they were also getting stuck. This makes the whole approach of creating indexes concurrently via script is vulnerable.

Any ideas how this can be made full proof without manual intervention? If not, what are other effective ways to contain index sizes on postgreSQL in automated fashion on large and busy tables.

Comment: invalid index usually due to concurrent index creation cancelled when running. Does the index creation finish successfully ?

Comment: What do you mean by "containing index size"? An index has the size it needs, and that size is not configurable. `CREATE/DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY` still requires an exclusive lock on the table, but only for a short duration. There is no way to avoid that, and on a busy server that can be disrupive.

Comment: What I meant was to reduce index size on PG tables that grow over time - which can be done using reindex table / create - drop index but both of which are intrusive techniques

Comment: Will aggressive vacuum setting help in maintaining index size/reducing index bloat?

Answer (score 0):

To benefit with concurrent build of indexes in script, you need to add logic in next commands (as you can't put in transaction). Simply check if index is not INVALID in next line and if it is, abort script.

Also I would reverse actions: first you build new index concurrently. If success, drop old one.

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-createindex.html:

> If a problem arises while scanning the table, such as a deadlock or a
>   uniqueness violation in a unique index, the CREATE INDEX command will
>   fail but leave behind an "invalid" index. This index will be ignored
>   for querying purposes because it might be incomplete; however it will
>   still consume update overhead.

and

> Another difference is that a regular CREATE INDEX command can be
>   performed within a transaction block, but CREATE INDEX CONCURRENTLY
>   cannot.

Comment: How to abort ? We checked when we tried to DROP INDEX /  DROP INDEX CONCURRENTLY - both were also stuck intermittently and reindex was taking lot of time to remove INVALID index that was created

Comment: reindex will rebuild invalid indexes not concurrently. how to abort what?..

Comment: How to remove the invalid index as mentioned even DROP INDEX were stuck when we tried to drop the invalid index.

Comment: wait till the relation gets free of lock and drop it. otherwise cancel/terminate backends and do the maintenance